# Size snackbar message based on text length

Tags: html, css

I have a snackbar message pop up when there is a successful patch or post in my application. These messages can be short or long sometimes based on the context of the object being updated.

This originally was set to `left: 50%` however I changed it because sometimes the message way not centered correctly. How can I make this snackbar always centered no matter how long the text is?

```
#snackbar {
     visibility: hidden;
     min-width: 250px;
     margin-left: -125px;
     background-color: $apple;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 16px;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     left: 40%;
     bottom: 30px;
 }
```

HTML is as follows

```
<body>
    <%= render "shared/sidenav" if current_user %>
    <div id=<%= "#{'main' if current_user}" %>>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}", id: 'alert' %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <div id="snackbar"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Snackbar is visible upon an HTTP request.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please post your HTML as well. and also some more of your CSS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` for this:

```css
#snackbar {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="snackbar">
  <p>Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.</p>
</div>
```

#### Small Example

```css
#snackbar {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="snackbar">
  <p>Eleifend nec eget.</p>
</div>
```

`left` is based off of the left side of the box. `Translate` is based on the width of the box, so this essentially moves the left edge of the box to the middle of the element's parent and then brings it back 50 percent of the box width.